# Formvalidation.io: event when certain field is valid

Tags: javascript, formvalidation.io

I have a beginner's question on [Formvalidation.io](https://formvalidation.io/). Maybe it's not even specific for that library but more related to Javascript in general.

I'd like to disable a validator after a certain field (let's say its name is `postcode`) has been validated and is valid. However, all my approaches result in either the validator not being disabled or being disabled if *any* field of my form is valid (not only the specific one).

I use the [core.field.valid](https://formvalidation.io/guide/events/core.field.valid) event and the library's documentation states:

> The event parameter presents the field name.

I'm uncertain how that happens.

I tried:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
 const fv = FormValidation.formValidation(
  document.getElementById('adminForm'),
  {
   fields: {
    postcode: {
     validators: {
      notEmpty: {
       message: 'Please enter a postcode.'
      }
     }
    }
   },

   plugins: {   
     submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
    defaultSubmit: new FormValidation.plugins.DefaultSubmit(),
    trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger({
     event: {
      postcode: 'change',
     }
    })
   }
  }
    );

 fv.on('core.field.valid', function(e) {
  if (e.field === 'postcode') {
   fv.disableValidator('postcode');
  }
 }); 
});
```

But the if-condition is not true even when the field is validated and valid.
(tried to adapt it from the example given [here](https://formvalidation.io/guide/examples/showing-all-messages/))

I also tried what I found in the documentation on the [on() method](https://formvalidation.io/guide/api/on) (as it states regarding `function(field)`: "field is name of invalid field"):

```js
const validFieldHandler = function(postcode) {
    fv.disableValidator('postcode');
};

fv.on('core.field.valid', validFieldHandler);
```

Result is the same (validator is not disabled).

The following however (as probably to expect) disables the validator if *any* field of the form is valid.

```
fv.on('core.field.valid', function(e) {
    fv.disableValidator('postcode');
});
```

Thank you for any advice you can offer! It's my first question here, so please let me know if you need additional information!

Best regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself:

```js
fv.on('core.field.valid', function(field) {
  if (field === 'postcode') {
   fv.disableValidator('postcode');
  }
});
```